# Python: how to extract only keyword arguments from `kwargs` dict accepted by a certain function

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I need to write a wrapper of two functions, and possibly avoid code (function signature) duplication. This is what I have in mind:

```py
def func1(arg1, arg2=1, arg3=""):
  pass

def func2(arg4, arg5=None):
  pass

def wrapper(arg1, arg2, arg4, **kwargs):
  # extract from kwargs arguments supported by func1()
  kwargs1 = extract_func1_kwargs(kwargs)
  func1(arg1, arg2, **kwargs1)

  # pass remaining arguments to func2()
  kwargs2 = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k not in kwargs1}
  func2(arg4, **kwargs2)
```

Any good suggestion about the implementation of `extract_func1_kwargs()`?

Comment: The duplicate question shows you how to get the signature of `func1` including its keyword args, so then it's straightforward to filter `kwargs` down to only the keys that correspond to keyword args of `func1`.